# Ruby & Google Places API: Empty fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I'm trying to use the Google Places API ([here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)) in a ruby on rails app. I'm using a gem called `google_places` ([here](https://github.com/rahilsondhi/google_places)). As far as I know the gem simply allows an easy interface to send the required HTTP requests and parse the JSON output into ruby hashes. I'm using the following code in my controller:

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new("(my api key)")
@spotList = @client.spots(-100, 73.1957362, :radius => "5000")
```

And in the view, I use the following to display the places:

```
<%  @spotList.each do |x| %>
  <%= x.name %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Now that works just fine, but if I replace `x.name` with `x.formatted_address` or `x.address_components`, I just get a blank page. I tried printing these fields in the log too, and I just a blank line of output. I've tried a lot of different latitudes and longitudes, and I'm getting names of banks with the current ones, which should have addresses.

I don't understand what's going on. I think I'm using the Google Places API incorrectly, since the `google_places` returns some other fields correctly. Can anyone please shed some light on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on this,

parse through @spotList and take out the reference of each place returned in response.
Now,
@client.spot "reference" will give you the data which contains the x.formatted_address or x.address_components.